# Creating triggers in order to implement ranking on a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have not ever worked on triggers in SQL Server 2008. So I don't have any idea how to do it.

I have a game application, I'm keeping track of the number of questions played & total number of questions answered correctly. I'm also saving the average time taken for each question played.

Now I want to record the rank depending upon percentage of answers correct and If there is a tie we will check the time taken. I have to do all this using triggers.

```
  id   | playerID | CompetitionID  | NoOfCOrrectANswers | NoOfPlayedQuestions | TimeTaken 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      3             203              4                       8                  8.4
  2      56            203              9                      18                 13
  3      67            203              16                     45                 15
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: start by creating a simple trigger to understand how they work then build in to more complex ones.   when you have a trigger that isn't behaving as expected, post the code here and people can help

Comment: Just a thought. By why not just keep track of the raw data such a player 1 answered question 1 in 2 seconds and so on. Then create a view on top of the table working out the averages etc. You can also use the SQL 2008 rank function in the view. Triggers can be a performance killer when a table is being hit often and hard. With a view you would be able to calculate your required values when needed and only when needed.

Comment: If you can add you source table's definition i.e. the table with the data of how a player answered and the target table definition I could probably help you a little more. Without the table definitions I am not going to be helpfull.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention but I have already added that PlayerRank field in the table. Below are my all requirements/conditions for the trigger: 1. whenever a new row is added to the table we need to update rank for all the records with same COmpetitionID 2. the player who has answered more no of corrected answers will have a better rank may be Rank 1. 3. If two players have same no. of correct answers then we will look for the time taken. player with less time taken value will have better rank and if they have same time then they will have same rank. I hope its all clear now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should not take this road as number of updates will be high. You might add [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or [rank()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function to a query that presents results of a competition.

That being said, if you feel that you absolutely must persist ranking info in a table, add a column

```
alter table ATable add PlayerRank int
```

and create a trigger on ATable

```
create trigger RankingTrigger on ATable
after insert, update, delete
as
-- We don't want queries in a trigger to mess up with "Rows affected"
   set nocount on
-- If any of the following columns are mentioned in a query
-- Always true for insert and delete, but we will save updates
-- if we skip processing when columns participating in ranking 
-- are not changed
   If update (NoOfCOrrectANswers)
      OR update(NoOfPlayedQuestions)
      OR update(TimeTaken)
   begin
      -- CTE that returns primary key and rank by competition.
      -- I've changed your condition (percent of correct answers)
      -- As it would rank players with one correct answer over those
      -- who answered 100 questions and got only one wrong. If you
      -- want to change it, replace NoOfCOrrectANswers with 
      -- NoOfCOrrectANswers / NoOfPlayedQuestions
      ; with theRank as (
        select ID, row_number() over (partition by CompetitionID
                                      order by NoOfCOrrectANswers DESC,
                                               TimeTaken DESC) rn
          from ATable
      -- Only changed competitions
         where CompetitionID in
      -- Inserted table is available in trigger and OUTPUT clause
      -- of insert, update, delete statements.
      -- It contains newly added/changed rows
      -- We are using it here to filter only changed competitions
      -- Similary, Deleted table hold a copy of removed rows for delete 
      -- and old values for update
         (
            select CompetitionID
              from Inserted
            union
            select CompetitionID
              from Deleted
         )
      )
      update ATable
      -- Update to rank from theRank CTE
         set PlayerRank = theRank.rn
        from ATable
        -- All records participation in affected competitions
          inner join theRank
             on ATable.ID = theRank.ID
        -- Only change if really changed
        -- This part is very likely not needed. I have never tested
        -- to see if it affects performance
            and isnull(ATable.PlayerRank, 0) <> theRank.rn
   end
```

Comment: The CTE in a view would probably be much less of a performance killer so I agree that the trigger is probably not the way to go. Oh by the way in your answer you say  -- Inserted table is available in trigger only. You can access the inserted and deleted tables in UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE statements since 2005 if you use the OUTPUT clause. I found the output clause to be one of those hidden SQL gems.

Comment: @Namphibian Thank you for pointing out this mistake. It slipped my mind.